# How to import/add translated strings having inline styles?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I've imported a .po file having Spanish translations. The import was successful but some translation strings were skipped because they contain disallowed HTML.

From UI, I found that some translations were not translated. So I tried them adding those via the translate admin interface (Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface)

I could see the original text having inline style like following.

[image]

But when I tried to add a Spanish (Latin American) Translation and hit 'Save translations' getting the following error.

> The submitted string contains disallowed HTML:`<span style="color:#0098CF">Hola</span>`

I've enabled Translatable all *HTML text formats* under multilingual settings  (Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Multilingual settings)

[image]

It's working when I remove inline style add translation   like the following. So I guess it's not supporting inline styles and classes.

```
<span> Hola </span>
```

What could be the problem? I found a function in `function locale_string_is_safe($string)` under includes/locale.inc file. Do I need to do any tweaks with that?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your guess is correct,`locale_string_is_safe`  "Check that a string is safe to be added or imported as a translation." if you want to ignore your job you should patch it for a while , 
change it to

```
function locale_string_is_safe($string) {
  return TRUE:
}
```

after your job  revert it.

Comment: Awesome! that works!! thanks zhilevan  you saved my day:)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan your welcome my friend :) . we are here to help each others ;)

Comment: Is there not any other solution since this is hacking core?thanks

Comment: @sokratis I dont spend more time on it maybe there is but I dont know it

Comment: @sokratis – Added no-hacking answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative without hacking the core. You simply could unset the validation for the translation interface form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // That's the form ID of the translation interface.
  if ($form_id == 'i18n_string_locale_translate_edit_form') {

    // Let's check at least for a user's role first.
    global $user;
    if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {

      // Simply unset the validation. Done.
      unset($form['#validate']);
    }
  }
}
```